# How to number gathered equations using single number

Tags: latex

I want to number gathered equations, but single number for several equations. Following is the code I've used. But it results numbering both equations. I want to equations to be justified, not right aligned.  Spilt and align environment right align the equations. Is there any way to do this?

```
\begin{gather}
\eta_{c1} P_{pv}(k) + \eta_{c2} P_{bat}(k) \leq P_{conG,rate} \\\
P_{grid} + P_{load} \geq -P_{conG,rate} 
\end{gather}
```

Answer (score 2):

After \ you can put \nonumber this way you can avoid having both equations numbered

Answer (score 2):

Here is a cleaner solution than using `\nonumber`.  Using `gathered` or `aligned` environments inside an `equation` environment groups the equations and assigns one number to them.  This is recommended by the `amsmath` [user guide](https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/amsldoc.pdf).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \begin{gathered}
        \eta_{c1} P_{pv}(k) + \eta_{c2} P_{bat}(k) \leq P_{conG,rate}
        \\
        P_{grid} + P_{load} \geq -P_{conG,rate}
    \end{gathered}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
        \eta_{c1} P_{pv}(k) + \eta_{c2} P_{bat}(k) &\leq P_{conG,rate}
        \\
        P_{grid} + P_{load} &\geq -P_{conG,rate}
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: compiled]

Answer (score 0):

As said by Good Luck, you can add `\nonumber` at the end of the line before `\\`.

A problem I encountered was that when adding a `\label{label_name}` the `Eq.~\ref{label_name}` showed as (for example) `Eq.2.5` instead of `Eq.2`. I've managed to sort this by moving the `\label{label_name}` to the row below `\begin{gather}`. So for example my code would look like this:

```
\begin{gather}
\label{labe_name}
e=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n!}}\\
\begin{aligned}
&\textit{\small Where:}\nonumber\\
&\textit{\small $1^{st}$ line and more explanations to fill the line} \nonumber\\
&\textit{\small $2^{nd}$ line}\nonumber\\
&\textit{\small ext \dots}\nonumber\\
\end{aligned}
\end{gather}
```

Make sure to have this packages:

```
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
```